# How to get the number of columns of a char array?

Tags: c++, c

Is there a way to get the number of columns a `char array` has?

It's declared like this: `static const char *countries[][2] = { ... };`

But I want to get it dynamically, so without typing '2' myself

Comment: Please clarify by showing some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to pass the size along with the array. There might exist system/compiler/library dependent ways, but it's not a good idea to rely on such functionalities.
If you're using the C++ standard library, you'd better use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), which carries more metadata, such as the [`size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) you're interested in.

Comment: Yeah, but `vector` is compared to a simple `char` array much bigger and slower right? That's why I try to avoid vectors

Comment: I don't have data about the speed, but the memory occupancy is the same, since it internally uses a `char*`, just like you'd do, together with some `int`s, to store the size, just like you'd do.

Comment: I didn't know that the memory occupancy was for both the same until now, thanks. Going to change it all to `vector`.

Comment: Anyway, I think that the speed is also the same, since it does the same operations that you'd do, in order to carry the size together with your vector. Maybe you wouldn't need the operations to dynamically expand the vector, but it's just an `if`.

Comment: Yes, speed would be approximately the same because they're internally equal, thanks a lot for the knowledge.

Comment: @Houssni avoid premature optimization concerns. Unless you already **know for sure** that a piece of your code will be a bottleneck for your application (say, an inner, tight loop) or a huge memory hog, concentrate on making the code correct and readable. Standard library code is usually optimized in a decent compiler. Special purpose optimizations are usually needed only in an application's hot-spots (and you must profile to find them).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Yes you are right, but the problem is that I want to try and prevent such problems from the very beginning so I won't need to face them later on. But I am starting to think that it is not necessary at all?

Comment: @Houssni much depends on what performance your app really requires. If it spends most of the time waiting for network connections or user interaction usually squeezing the last MIPS out of it is wasted effort (although memory footprint may be an issue). Unless you **know* your code require high efficiency (e.g. 3D real-time animations, heavy math, etc.), putting your effort in app general structure design will save you a lot of headaches when hunting for bugs (and plain C arrays are a source of bugs!). Try only to avoid "first-order" inefficiencies (i.e. avoid a O(n^3) search algorithm ;-)

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Thank you very much for the explanation and knowledge, I am not quite experienced enough to understand this line: "Try only to avoid "first-order" inefficiencies (i.e. avoid a O(n^3) search algorithm"

Comment: O(n^3) is a [math notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to express the complexity of an algorithm. O(n^3) means (very roughly) that an algorithm uses a time proportional to the cube of the number or the element being processed. The part in parentheses was indeed a joke: it is a well-known computer science fact that a [sequential search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) (a really trivial algorithm) is O(n), thus **MUCH** better than O(n^3). Anyone writing an O(n^3) search algorithm must have really tried hard to make it that inefficient :-)

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I am going to do some research about it, thanks for the links you provided, sounds very hard and complicated.

Comment: @Houssni the article on Wikipedia is very math-oriented (students which study computer science ore engineering have to grok that), but probably you'll find easier explanations googling around. A programmer usually is not required to understand all those details, unless he is really developing optimization techniques.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Yes, so it's obvious that I don't need to understand all that but I am very studious and it might come in handy later on if I want to concentrate on optimization technieques so I am going to study it anyway.

Comment: -1, since this answer is blunt wrong. Sure that you may obtain all different length in the two dimensions easily with the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @JensGustedt sizeof is compile-time stuff. It only works on statically sized arrays. Since the question states "But I want to get it dynamically, so without typing '2' myself". `sizeof` is to be excluded. Also, if you use `sizeof`, you need to know the static size of the array in every function you pass it, which is equivalent to passing it along as an argument, just less flexible,

Comment: @Houssni O(n^3) basically means "three nested 0-n loops" (it's more subtle than this, but the three nested loops is what you should avoid). The idea is that, if you make a loop over 10 elements, it'll be 10 iterations. If you nest two 0-10 loops, it'll be 100 iterations. If you nest three 0-10 loops, it'll be 1000 iterations, and so on. If you change from 10 to 11, the single loop will get from 10 to 11, while the triple loop will bump from 1000 to 1331.

Comment: @GiulioFranco, his example is a static array, and he is asking for that. I understood his "dynamically" as "automatically" since then he is talking of the "2". For me the question reads that he wants to now the length of an array who's length is determined by the initializer, and not by providing it inside the `[]`.

Comment: That's also a meaningful interpretation, which I didn't think of. Anyway, I think my suggestion of using a more flexible tool is still valid. You can use sizeof to get the size of the array, but that's only possible where the definition is visible. If you want to pass it to a function which is size-agnostic, you still need to pass the size along. Using a vector just makes this easier, with a usually negligible performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you may. Statically initialized arrays can be inspected with the `sizeof` operator easily. The following snippet (in C) prints all sizes that are assoiated to your 2D array of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *countries[][2] = { { "dfdf", "dss" }, { "ss"}, { "toto"}};

int main(void) {
  printf("dim0 %zu, dim1 %zu, elements %zu\n",
         sizeof countries/sizeof countries[0],
         sizeof countries[0]/sizeof countries[0][0],
         sizeof countries/sizeof countries[0][0]
         );
}
```